# Is there any way to understand why a chiral rotation shifts $\theta$ besides the usual "path integral measure" computation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, quantum-chromodynamics

I'm looking for a way to understand why a chiral rotation

$$ \Psi \to e^{i \alpha \gamma_5} \Psi $$

shifts the QCD $\theta$ parameter: $\theta \to \theta + c \alpha$. (I know that it also has an effect on possible mass terms. However mass terms do have to do anything with the bosons and thus I don't think this change of the mass terms yields a term involving the bosons. But please correct me if I'm wrong.)

I understand the chiral anomaly, i.e. why $\partial_\mu J^{\mu 5} \neq 0$ and I'm looking for a way to understand why this observation means that we should add the term $c \partial_\mu J^{\mu 5}$ to the Lagrangian $\mathcal {L} \to \mathcal{L} + \Delta \mathcal{L}_\theta = \mathcal{L} + c \partial_\mu J^{\mu 5} $.

**I know that the standard derivation of this is the Fujikawa path measure method. This proof is, of course, mathematically fine. However, it is also quite abstract. While I'm not doubting the end result, I want to understand it from a different perspective if possible. (If there is a non-technical summary of the idea behind Fujikawa's proof, this would be, of course, awesome, too.)**